# Rails' Ransack Search with check_box for an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ransack

I got lost when I use 'ransack', a Rails Serching gem.

What I want to do is to work check-boxes for an asociated model.

Here is my code.

shows_controller.rb

```
class ShowsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @q = Show.search(params[:q])
    @shows = @q.result(:distinct => true)
    @shows = @shows.joins(:tickets)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb                                                                                                       
      format.json { render json: @shows }
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Show's Title: " %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_cont %>
  <%= f.label "Buy at:" %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'q[shows_tickets_store_cont[]]', 'venue' %>At Venue
  <%= check_box_tag 'q[shows_tickets_store_cont[]]', 'ticketmaster' %>Ticketmaster
  <%= submit_tag "Find Now" %>
<% end %>

<% @shows.each do |show| %>
  <%= show.title %> | 
  <% show.tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <%= ticket.store %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

show.rb

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end
```

ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
end
```

When I wrote something in the search_field, checked the "check_box" and clicked "Find Now" button, the log showed like below;

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"title_cont"=>"something", "shows_tickets_store_cont"=>"venue"}, "commit"=>"Find Now"}
Show Load (1.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `shows`.* FROM `shows` INNER JOIN `tickets` ON `tickets`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` WHERE (`shows`.`title` LIKE '%something%') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

I have no idea why the SQL doesn't have `WHERE` clause for Ticket.store, in spite of ticket controller received "shows_tickets_title_cont"=>"venue".

Please, suggest solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the problems is because your second key is: `shows_tickets_store_con` but is should be `shows_tickets_store_cont`. It accepts attribute if it has predicate `_cont`.

**Ransack documentation:**

https://github.com/ernie/ransack

```
cont (contains) and start (starts with) are just two of the available search predicates. See Constants for a full list.
```

**# Edited 1**

I made investigation a bit.

I do not think that your approach is good for your situation. If all the `checkboxes` are selected then you will have problems with your meta search - you have to set another `predicate`. In your situation it could be in predicate - because you use `multiple values` (checkboxes).

**To have SQL like:**

```
"shows_tickets_store" IN ('venue','something')
```

**Possible predicates:**

- https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching
- https://github.com/ernie/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/constants.rb

**Also read this:**

- https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/20
- https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/53

Comment: i am recognizing i should use thinking sphinx or sunspot or elasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks thesis. I will stop to think about it.